# Reason why this for loop isn't working in JavaScript when hardcoding worked fine?

Tags: javascript

Previously, I was hardcoding

```
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "Su";
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "Mo";
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "Tu";
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = "We";
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = "Th";
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = "Fr";
  // weekdays_row.insertCell(6).innerHTML = "Sa";
```

So, I wanted to make a for loop,

```
  var weekdays = ["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Th","Fri","Sat","Sun"];

  for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    weekdays_row.insertCell(i).innerHTML = weekdays[i];

  }
```

which led my very simple web app to crash. Any ideas why this isn't working? Sorry if it's very simple; I'm new to JavaScript!

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Use `var` instead of int
`for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your issue is about that `i` variable is typed as `int`, so JS is not a typed language, so you don't need to define its variable type, so try to replace the `int i = 0` to `let i = 0`, that should work.

Comment: Oh my gosh, such a silly mistake. Veryyy new to Javascript, sorry. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the **DataType** you are using, you can ***declare a variable*** using `let` or `var` or `const` in javascript

```
for (let i=0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
   weekdays_row.insertCell(i).innerHTML = weekdays[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int type is not a valid javascript variable declaration method, use `let` or `var` or `const`

[variables w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)